# In Rust, why can higher-level references be assigned to lower-level references, and why not the other way around?

Tags: rust, reference, pass-by-reference

Rust allows assigning references with a higher level of indirection to references with a lower level of indirection. For instance, the compiler allows assigning a `&&&&&&` to a `&`:

```rust
fn main() {
    let mut some_number = 5;

    // assign an &&&&&&i32 to an &i32, which works.
    let reference : &i32 = &&&&&&some_number;
}
```

This also works for function parameters:

```rust
fn main() {
    let num = 5;

    // ref1 is an &&i32
    let ref1 = &&num;
    
    // Pass an &&i32 to a function parameter, which itself is an &i32 (works)
    func(ref1);
}

fn func(test: &i32) {
    println!("^^^^ This works!");
}
```

I've learned that this works because of **automatic dereferencing**, which allows the Rust compiler to dereference a type as much as it needs to match some other type (please correct me if I'm wrong on this).

However, Rust doesn't seem to allow assigning lower-indirection references to higher-indirection references:

```rust
fn main() {
    let num = 5;
    
    // Try assigning an &i32 to an &&i32 (error)
    let ref1 : &&i32 = &num;
}
```

This results in an `expected &i32, found integer` compiler error. We get a similar compiler error when testing this with function parameters:

```rust
fn main() {
    let num = 5;
    
    // ref1 is an &&&i32
    let ref1 = &&&num;
    
    // Try passing an &&&i32 to a function parameter of type &&&&&i32 (error)
    func(ref1);
}

fn func(test: &&&&&i32) {
    println!("^^^^^^^^ This does not work!")
}
```

Here, we get a `mismatched types` error as well. Something I'm curious about, however, is that the compiler output isn't exactly what we expect. Rather than `expected &&&&&i32, found &&&i32`, the compiler error is `expected &&i32, found integer`. It seems that the compiler dereferenced both references until one was no longer a reference - why does it dereference **both** references? I thought it only dereferenced whatever was being passed to the function.

Overall, my main question is
**Why, exactly, should assigning lower-indirection to higher-indirection references be disallowed when assigning higher-indirection to lower-indirection references is allowed? What is so different about these two things, that their behaviors must be different as well?**

Comment: I'm voting to close as opinion-based. Why the compiler output is different is an interesting question (although it doesn't really matter), but your main question cannot be answered factually, I believe.

Answer (score 1):

`&&T` can be coerced to `&T` because of [deref coercion](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/reference/type-coercions.html#coercion-types) ("`&T` or `&mut T` to `&U` if `T` implements `Deref<Target = U>`") and the [`impl Deref<Target = T> for &T`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/ops/trait.Deref.html#impl-Deref-for-%26T) the other way is not possible because there exists no `impl Deref<Target = &T> for T`.
By repeatet application `&&&&&&T` can be coerced to `&T`

As to why one is allowed while the other isn't well if implicit referencing was allowed everywhere tracking ownership would be even harder than it currently is, we have this problem already with auto-referencing of method receivers.

```rust
let s = String::from("Hello");
my_fun(s);
```

The question "Does `s` get moved?" can't be answered without looking at the definition of `my_fun` if we allow automatic referencing.

Comment: I agree that implicit referencing from `i32` to `&i32` could be confusing because then the user wouldn't know whether or not a variable was moved. However, I was referring to why implicit referencing between references (such as `&&i32` to `&&&&&&i32`) isn't allowed. Could you clarify on this?

Comment: Allowing the latter (via the `impl Deref<Target = &T> for T`) would automatically enable the former too.